# Logo sketch critique

Tags: logo, illustration, sketching

Logo for Hardy Boys Media, a social media marketing company. Fairly small, started by two brothers, a few big clients. Here are some preliminary sketches to get an idea of the direction to go.

Andy the co-founder wants to play off the name of course, they already use a magnifying glass in their current logo, and suggested doing something 'comic book' like. Some keywords we touched on were 'engaging', focused, personable, 'detective' quality.

p.s. - Illustrations are not my wheelhouse so any suggestions I will happily look into. Thanks all.[image: Illustrations]

Comment: Just FYI.. I'm not a lawyer, but my inclination is the term "Hardy Boys" is copyrighted... So, unless the owner's name is *actually* "Hardy" and there are more than 1 of them, and they are male..... there may be an issue there. (You can use the name if it is *actually* your name, regardless of copyright.)

Comment: Their last name is Hardy, both male and brothers.

Comment: Cool.`:)` I wasn't trying to be critical, merely informative. `:)`

Comment: No problem, now that that's taken care of, any thoughts or concerns on the logo direction?

Comment: Sorry. I voted to close. This question is far too broad and opinion based in my view. Design choices made based upon 3 paragraphs of text and a few rough sketches will *rarely* be *good* design choices.

Answer (score 2):

Boys. Plural.

So if you're going to do drawings of heads or hats, or anything else representative of people, it needs to be 2 of them.

Magnifying glass is wrong for social media marketing. It's micro, whereas social media marketing is macro.

Pen nib is wrong. Too narrow.

The hats ideas show most promise, and are the best analogy, because a social media marketing company can be considered to:

1. Wear many hats
2. Be wearing the hats of their clients
3. Sufficiently old and reverential that hats are good/cool
4. To have crossed town to represent a client (hat on appropriately)

etc.

So I'd say two hats of the detective type are ideal, at an angle to one another that's friendly yet formal.

A hat stand holding the two hats might work, too. But could get too busy looking.

Two ties is too boy's school-ish to be considered "good".

---

the drawing at the bottom right, whilst not appropriate for this, is very good! Will likely make for a great icon.